# Two ajax posts, the first one works fine, while second one displays parse error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5

I have two ajax calls with basically identical lines but only one works.

First Ajax post :

```
$("#languageswitcher").change(function(){


   var locale=$(this).val();
   //alert(111);
   //console.log(111);
  var _token =$("input[name=_token]").val();


   $.ajax({

      url:"/language",
       type:"POST",
       data:{locale:locale,_token:_token},
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(data){

         console.log(data);  
       },
       error: function(ts) {


           //alert(ts.responseText);
       },
       beforeSend:function(){
           console.log(locale);

       },
       complete:function(data){

           window.location.reload(true);

       }
      });

    }) ;
```

Second one: when I take off `dataType:"json"` it displays success on alert but send nothing, with the `dataType:"json"` it displays parse error on alert.
i tried with `JSON.stringfy()` but still displaying the same problem.

```
$("#change_group").change(function(){

    var group=$(this).val();

    var _token=$("input[name=_token]").val();

    $.ajax({

       url:"/setgroup",
       type:"POST",
        data:{group:group,_token:_token},
        dataType:'json',
       success:function(data,status){
          alert(status);  
        },
       error:function(data,status){
            alert(status);
        },

       beforeSend:function(group){

        },
       complete:function(data){
            window.location.reload();
        }


       });



    });
```

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Is it possible the endpoint simply isn't functioning as expected, and has nothing to do with your JavaScript?  Have you tried making the call from [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)?

Comment: Postman displays 500 Internal server Error  @AlexanderNied

Comment: if `500 Internal server Error` the you need to fix the server or make sure the request is correct

Answer (score 0):

well it's the token , the token sent can't be verified so i switched and used get .